# What happened to the Python API for Interactive Markers?

Tags: ros, python, ros-groovy, interactive-markers

[image: Rosanswers logo]

With the desktop-full installation, I'm trying to run the interactive_markers_tutorials python node and I get this error message:

```
$ rosrun interactive_marker_tutorials simple_marker.py 

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/ros/groovy/stacks/visualization_tutorials/interactive_marker_tutorials/python/simple_marker.py", line 35, in <module>
    from interactive_markers.interactive_marker_server import *
ImportError: No module named interactive_markers.interactive_marker_server
```

This works in Fuerte. The C++ node works fine in Groovy. It looks like the Python code is missing in the installation.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/54278/what-happened-to-the-python-api-for-interactive-markers?/) by [duy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3918/duy/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2013-02-04

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This had been fixed for some time, but not released. I've triggered a release into groovy (1.9.5).

---

Originally posted by [dgossow](https://answers.ros.org/users/1564/dgossow/) with karma: 1444 on 2013-02-05

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [duy](https://answers.ros.org/users/3918/duy/) on 2013-02-05**:
Thanks!